# cmake command line fails to find compiler, but cmake-gui does

Tags: windows, cmake

I have a windows batch script that calls cmake command line with a preload cache and a build output directory. This correctly identifies my Windows SDK but not the compiler.

When I run CMake GUI with the same source / build directories, it works perfectly. I've been going crazy trying to hunt down any differences between the two methods, but nothing yet.

**Script**
(The full script is fairly long, but I believe I've trimmed it down to the essentials here)

```
REM Check for boost dependency and install local to source tree
SET BOOST_TARGET=%BOOST_INSTALL%
SET BOOST=boost-1.63.0
SET LINK=src\3rd_party

IF NOT EXIST "%LINK%\%BOOST%" (
  REM There is additional code here to handle path checking, but all safe ...
  xcopy /Q /Y /I /E "%BOOST_TARGET%\%BOOST%" "%LINK%\%BOOST%"
)

SET BUILDDIR=BUILD

REM do cmake part ... Preload.cmake is a separate file with cmake SET commmands
cmake ^
-G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ^
-C Preload.cmake ^
-B "%BUILDDIR%" -S src
```

Configuring CMake-gui with the same build and source directories causes no issues, but the above script shows the following error.

**CMakeError.log** (Excerpt)

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.180.61344 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 2/21/2022 3:57:30 PM.
Project "C:\myproject\BUILD\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\myproject\src\3rd_party.obj' [C:\myproject\BUILD\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\myproject\BUILD\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\myproject\BUILD\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\myproject\src\3rd_party.obj' [C:\myproject\BUILD\CMakeFiles\3.14.4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.78
```

Comment: Even if you want to self-answer, the **question post** should provide **all relevant information** about the problem, including the code and the error message.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev I will add more information to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my process to reduce the script to illustrate the issue, I discovered my problem.

**My script set a local environment variable named LINK that apparently broke CMake.** I haven't investigated more to know whether this is a limitation with CMake or my project, but the workaround is helpful enough to me now.

For example, my script was

```
SET LINK=C:\path\to\something
REM do something with %LINK%
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -B BUILD -S src
```

The output would report that it could not identify the compiler, and the error pointed to being unable to find "C:\path\to\something.obj". I didn't see the connection at first.

Again, not sure if the issue was with CMake or what CMake used from my project to test the compiler.

**My fix** was to use a variable name other than LINK.